# I want to see a if a file contains any sentence using grep or perl

Tags: perl, unix, awk, grep, gawk

I have a large directory of files to look through on my desktop and I need to determine if any of the files contain English sentences. Is there an easy way to do this using grep or perl?
 so grep "some capital letter + some word + punctuation"

Comment: Welcome to SO, you should take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about). You should add code that you've tried or try searching on SO or google.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep '[[:punct:][:alpha:]]' *.files
```

Comment: ah I see, I think this is close. thanks!!

Comment: SO is turning into 'do my homework' for me site.

Comment: Thanks for the correction Stephane. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you want this?

```
find /some/large/dir | xargs grep "some string info with CAPS and !"
```

Comment: I don't have specific string info, I'm just looking to see if a file contains any English sentence.

Comment: You should use `-exec` instead of `xargs`.

Comment: @squiguy, yeah probably, just old habbit.  vaguely remember having issues with exec in the past (due to quoting and escaping in the command i want to call)...  Do you have any reference as to why `-exec` is better?

Comment: @Lucas, `xargs` expects a blank (SPC, TAB, NL) separated list of words where blanks can be escaped with quotes or backslash. `find` doesn't output in that format.

Comment: @sch: it does as long as the filenames (not "words") don't contain blanks.  if they do, you simply use find's -print0 and xargs -0.

Comment: @ysth, as I said, it's blanks (SPC, TAB, NL) **and quotes** (single quote, double quote or backslash). `-print0/xargs -0` are not standard, `find -exec cmd {} +` is. `xargs` considers _words_ that can be filenames or anything. And IMO, it's not _as long as the filenames don't contain those characters_, it's _as long as you can guarantee that the filenames won't ever contain such characters and that that code won't be copy-pasted into contexts where they may_, so IMO again, we shouldn't advertise this kind of usage on SO (or at least not without a big warning).

Comment: @sch, for the sake of completeness (being an example on SO) can you provide the full find command equivalent to my example?

Comment: `find /some/large/dir -exec grep "some string info with CAPS and !" {} +` or to guarantee that the filename be always displayed: `find /some/large/dir -exec grep "some string info with CAPS and !" /dev/null {} +`

Comment: is this close to operable? 
find -name "*.html" | xargs grep "[4+[:alnum:]][[:space:]][[:punct:]]"